# Calculation of the optimal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I have 5 matrices $A, B, C, D$ and $E$, all of them are square matrices of the same size. I have a set of equations such that:

$$A\cdot B=C, \quad A\cdot B^2=D, \quad A\cdot B^3=E$$

For given $A, C, D$ and $E$, how can I approximate $B$? Solving for $B$ yields different matrices and I am trying to find the $B$ that gives the minimal deviation when plugged in. In a sense, I am trying to do a regression analysis but matrix-wise.

Comment: If $A$ is invertible, then from the first equation, $B=A^{-1}\cdot C$.  (also, given your equations, A, B, C, D, E are not only square matrices, as given; they must also be of the same dimension, else multiplication in each may not be defined.

Comment: Also, $B^2 = A^{-1} \cdot D = (A^{-1}\cdot B)^2$, and $B^3 = A^{-1}E = B \cdot B^2 = B^3$

Comment: They are of the same dimension, I will edit that immediately but they do not yield the same matrix. I am looking for the compromise matrix that will yield the minimal error from C, D, and E. A is invertible. What I want to do is like a regression analysis but matrix-wise.